# Multiple Devices Automation through Appium

Tags: android, automation, appium

I have seen some articles and questions regarding Automation through Appium on multiple Android devices. I know that for Appium to work on multiple devices we need to give the device id to `udid` in the JAVA code.

what I really want to understand is how will Appium perform the same script on multiple devices? What if a command fails on one device and does not fail on the other device? will there be multiple servers running?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: you can experiment this by removing any device while the appium script is running

Comment: I will. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Possible! But there is no direct approach to do it. We have to start Appium server in different ports(Example: 4723, 4725,...). We have to get the udid of multiple devices connected to the system & have to set the capability.

If a command fails on one device it won't give any effect to other device. Since, We have 2 appium servers running.

Comment: Ok, Thats what I needed to know. Thanks. Gonna try automation on multiple devices.

Comment: One more thing. WIll using appium on multiple devices effect its performance?

Comment: No, There is no effect on Appium performance. Your system should be good to handle multiple appium servers that's it.

Comment: Thank you for the Response.

Comment: There is a minimal performance spike when establishing a new device. If you launch 100 at the same time, you might have some problems. 

We've also found some other issues (possibly related to our code - not worth investigating at this time) that have caused us to stagger launching new devices by a few seconds. You may find the same.

Comment: See https://medium.com/@setpace/parallel-execution-in-appium-1-7-dc60c4802082 for more info on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time same test will not fail on some other devices. Some reasons to fail on same platform and different devices might be size of devices and different device behavior in different manufactures.

If you write your test wisely keeping everything in mind then you will have very less test failure because of device.

Also to launch test on multiple device either you can launch multiple appium server or you can launch one server and create multiple sessions of it.

Test failure in one device will not affect test running in another device. As these are using different servers or sessions.